# Embed: Make an updating background transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I wrote up this embed here which takes weather info from the specified site as an embed, then duplicates it in hopes to change the alpha channel of the color white to transparent. I can't seem to come to a conclusion.
The issue is the weather app updates every 1 or 2 seconds. So I would need a loop as well IF I can even get the background to be transparent, which I haven't had any luck with yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta nameset="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ClearOutside</title>

  <style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: transparent;

  -ms-zoom: 0.5;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:blue">
  <a href="https://clearoutside.com/forecast/37.61/15.10">
    <img id="forecast" src="https://clearoutside.com/forecast_image_small/33.07/-106.02/forecast.png" /></a>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="505" height="41">

<script>
  document.getElementById("forecast").onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("forecast");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Should be `<iframe id="myframe"`

Comment: There is no way to change the white background color on an `iframe` using CSS. You will have to obtain an iframe source with an already transparent background.

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe? Are you allowed to change it (it is on the same network,..)? If no, then you won't be able to change it. Imagine the security risk if that were possible.

Comment: I see, would it be possible to then perhaps scan a selected area for all white pixels and replace those with nothing, aka be transparent?

Comment: i did find this, however i dont know how to implement that.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: @JP2K that is completely unrelated to an `iframe`. Do you know what an iframe is and how it works? As @cloned mentioned if being able to change an `iframe`(a HTML document that is embedded inside another document on a website, allowing you to include content from external sources on your pages) it would be a security risk.

Comment: Yes I am aware of an Iframe. I do not want to directly change the Iframe. What I want to achieve is copy the selected area of pixels in the Iframe then duplicate them below the Iframe box on the canvas. So that way I can choose which pixels I want to be transparent

Comment: Perhaps I could instead of using Iframe, I'll directly embed it. Would that be better? Sorry I'm a total noob